# How to calculated 3 months date based on given date JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

```js
function change()    {
    var date    =     new Date();
    var dd = date.getDate("startDate");
    var mm = date.getMonth("startDate")+1;
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear("startDate");
    var myDate=yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    
    var tmps = new Date(myDate).getTime();
    var newdate = (90*3600*24*1000)+tmps;
    var t=new Date(newdate);
    var dd= t.getDate();
    var mm=t.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy=t.getFullYear();
    var tdate=yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
    // alert(document.getElementById("endDate").value=tdate);
    return tdate;
}
document.write(change());
```

My problem is that the `tdate` value actually gives a `YYYY-M-DD` value, instead of a `YYYY-DD-MM`.

Comment: You need to check if the month is less than 9 and add 0 + mm

Comment: Thanks It worked but the value of enddate is always same

Comment: YYYY-DD-MM is a peculiar format that is bound to confuse the vast majority of people attempting to decipher it. None of the Date *get* methods take any arguments, so `date.getDate("startDate")` should be `date.getDate()`, and so on. Adding months is not trivial, adding 1 month to 31 January will result in 2 or 3 March, depending on whether it's a leap year or not.

Comment: Date.getDate and Date.getMonth do not accept any arguments. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a time library for JavaScript called [Moment](http://momentjs.com/). Your problem is trivial with this simple syntax:

```js
var m = moment().add(3,'months').format('YYYY-DD-MM');
alert('Three months from now in YYYY-DD-MM format is:\n' + m);
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The `moment()` constructor creates the current instant of time and has methods to manipulate and format it without all the details of time management algorithms that require debugging and testing.

Comment: While moment.js is a great library, an answer should not rely in a library that isn't tagged or noted in the OP. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change(myDate){
    var tmps = new Date(myDate).getTime();
    var newdate = (90*3600*24*1000)+tmps;
    var t=new Date(newdate);
    var dd= t.getDate() <10 ? "0"+t.getDate() : t.getDate();
    var mm=t.getMonth()+1 <10 ? "0"+(+t.getMonth()+1) : t.getMonth()+1;
    var yyyy=t.getFullYear();
    var tdate=yyyy+'-'+dd+'-'+mm; 
    alert(tdate);
document.getElementById("tdate").value = tdate;
}
change("2016-7-1"); // ==> 2016-29-09
//change(new Date("2016-8-1"));// ==> 2016-29-30
//change(new Date("2016/08/01"));// ==> 2016-29-10
//change(new Date(2016,(8-1),1));// ==> 2016-29-10
```

```html
<input type='text' id="tdate" value=''/>
```

Comment: when i change the start date then too the end date is 2017-01-18 not changing respective to start date

Comment: your code say that you want to get the date after 3 months, ye?

Comment: Yes but based on a given date it should calculate 3 months but its not happening when i change the start date then too its not changing and i want to calculate on 3 months (per month 30 days not 31 days or 28 or 29 days)

Comment: the answer updated now use `change("any valid date here");`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

```
var tdate = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
```

so you should not be surprised to get yyyy-mm-dd. ;-) Change it to:

```
var tdate = yyyy + '-' + dd + '-' + mm;
```

If you wish to get a date that is 3 months from now, you need to consider what happens when you add 3 months to say 31 December. In older versions of ECMAScript, 30 November 2015 + 3 months gave 1 March 2016. Newer versions will not allow the date to overrun the month, so the result will be 29 February.

E.g. in Firefox 49:

```js
var d = new Date(2015,10,30);
d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+3);
console.log(d); // 1 Mar 2016 or 29 Feb 2016 depending on implementation
```

Since you can't tell which version the host is compliant with, you will need to manually test whether the date has rolled over or not:

```js
function addMonths(date, months) {
  var startMonth = date.getMonth();
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);
  // If the new month isn't correct, set to last day of previous month
  if ((startMonth + +months)%12 != date.getMonth()) {
    date.setDate(0);
  }
  return date
}

var d = new Date(2015,10,31);
addMonths(d, 3);
console.log(d)
```

In your code, the Date *get* methods do not take any arguments, so any that are supplied are ignored, e.g.

```
date.getDate("startDate");
```

should be

```
date.getDate();
```

and so on. Also:

```
var date = new Date();
```

will create a new Date based on the host timezone offset, however when you then create a string based on its YYYY-MM-DD values and do:

```
 var myDate=yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
```

It is treated as a UTC date. For users west of Greenwich, the date will appear to be one day earlier.

If you wish to copy a date, simply provide it as the sole argument to the Date constructor:

```
var tmps = new Date(date);
```

Months should be added as indicated above. There are not exactly 90 days in every 3 month period, and there are not exactly 24 hours in every day in places where daylight saving is observed. So the combination of factors means that from time to time your algorithm for adding 3 months will seem to be randomly incorrect.

Lastly, a format of YYYY-DD-MM is certain to confuse the vast majority of people read it. Dates are largely misunderstood, so the best strategy is to write them in an unambiguous form with the month name used instead of the number. Or if you wish to use an only numeric form, the stick to well known standards like ISO 8601 YYYY-MM-DD.